# SQL command works in Oracle but returns absolutely nothing in laravel

Tags: laravel, oracle

So I am trying to display data from 4 different tables using the Join command in oracle.
This sql query when ran in oracle's sqldeveloper it works like a charm, but returns an empty string in Laravel when I try to dump the data using dd();
For context I am using DB Facades to hold this command before I process it in the controller.

```sql
select SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_id,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_nm,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_short_nm,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_t, 
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.lower_limit_q,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.upper_limit_q, 
       TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.st_d, 'DD MON YYYY') as st_d,
       TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.end_d, 'DD MON YYYY') as end_d, 
       TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.CREATE_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') as CREATE_DTM,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.create_id,
       TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.UPD_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') as UPD_DTM,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.upd_id,
       SUP_NOTIFICATION.supply_id,
       SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_NM,
       SUP_LOCATION.LOC_NM
FROM   SUP_NOTIFICATION 
       JOIN SUP_SUPPLY_LOC ON SUP_NOTIFICATION.SUPPLY_ID = SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_ID
       JOIN SUP_SUPPLY ON SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_C = SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_C
       JOIN SUP_LOCATION ON SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.LOC_C = SUP_LOCATION.LOC_C
order by notify_id DESC
```

I mostly got this reply from ChatGPT when I enquired how to do it, but it had no reply as to why it does not work in laravel.

Should I be using a query builder?

Comment: In PHP it isn't mandatory that SQL be in only on line. Try http://poorsql.com/ as an example formatter, play with the available options. It may make you SQL easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would make "models" of your tables in Laravel ORM and then use those models instead of just relying on SQL directly. You **could** use a raw sql query like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_id
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_nm
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_short_nm
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_t
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.lower_limit_q
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.upper_limit_q
    , TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.st_d, 'DD MON YYYY') AS st_d
    , TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.end_d, 'DD MON YYYY') AS end_d
    , TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.CREATE_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') AS CREATE_DTM
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.create_id
    , TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.UPD_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') AS UPD_DTM
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.upd_id
    , SUP_NOTIFICATION.supply_id
    , SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_NM
    , SUP_LOCATION.LOC_NM
FROM SUP_NOTIFICATION
JOIN SUP_SUPPLY_LOC ON SUP_NOTIFICATION.SUPPLY_ID = SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_ID
JOIN SUP_SUPPLY ON SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_C = SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_C
JOIN SUP_LOCATION ON SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.LOC_C = SUP_LOCATION.LOC_C
ORDER BY notify_id DESC";

$results = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

But that approach isn't recommended as it may open you to sql injection issues, so slightly better would be:

```
$results = DB::table('SUP_NOTIFICATION')
    ->join('SUP_SUPPLY_LOC', 'SUP_NOTIFICATION.SUPPLY_ID', '=', 'SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_ID')
    ->join('SUP_SUPPLY', 'SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.SUPPLY_C', '=', 'SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_C')
    ->join('SUP_LOCATION', 'SUP_SUPPLY_LOC.LOC_C', '=', 'SUP_LOCATION.LOC_C')
    ->select([
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_id',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_nm',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_short_nm',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.notify_t',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.lower_limit_q',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.upper_limit_q',
        DB::raw("TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.st_d, 'DD MON YYYY') AS st_d"),
        DB::raw("TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.end_d, 'DD MON YYYY') AS end_d"),
        DB::raw("TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.CREATE_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') AS CREATE_DTM"),
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.create_id',
        DB::raw("TO_CHAR(SUP_NOTIFICATION.UPD_DTM, 'DD MON YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') AS UPD_DTM"),
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.upd_id',
        'SUP_NOTIFICATION.supply_id',
        'SUP_SUPPLY.SUPPLY_NM',
        'SUP_LOCATION.LOC_NM'
    ])
    ->orderByDesc('notify_id')
    ->get();
```

**However** it is only the `to_char()` function that isn't directly supported by Laravel ORM, so if you already have models such as this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SupNotification extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'SUP_NOTIFICATION';

    protected $dates = [
        'st_d',
        'end_d',
        'CREATE_DTM',
        'UPD_DTM',
    ];
}
```

then allow PHP/Laravel to do the date formatting, e.g.

```
$notification = App\Models\SupNotification::find(1);

echo $notification->st_d->format('d M Y');
echo $notification->end_d->format('d M Y');
echo $notification->CREATE_DTM->format('d M Y, H:i:s');
echo $notification->UPD_DTM->format('d M Y, H:i:s');
```